# Функция if() в scss

Tags: scss

Подскажите, как описать следующее условие в SCSS для `class="block"`.

Если `class="block one"`, то `background: #cccccc`, а если `class="block two"`, то `background: #eeeeee`.

Правильно ли понимаю, что через функцию `if()`?

Comment: вам нужно просто сделать два селектора для разных классов

Comment: Вы хотите проверить наличие классов "one" & "two" посредством scss?